What is the difference between a data catalog policy tag and a "normal" data catalog tag?
I have actually gotten things to work properly (using the policy tag), yet I still don't understand the difference between the data catalog policy tag and the data catalog tag.
To be specific, I'm talking about comparing google_data_catalog_policy_tag and google_data_catalog_tag.
I initially assumed that the "regular" tag could not have policies associated with it, but Google's own documentation really seems to contradict this thinking. And while that link to Google's documentation suggests that regular tags could be used for implementing policy, this link (also Google's documentation) says that policy tags should be used.
Does anyone understand this mess at a deep level, and can you explain it clearly?

The regular tags are a way to add more metadata to an entry and implementing policies on top of that is just one of the ways you can use it.
While policy tags are used explicitly for BQ column-level access.
